# NodeJS extra field with byId();

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I am working on a nodeJS API, I have a model, and that model can have Media items, as you can see in my code here:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
qbuilder.byId(Model,req)
    .exec(
    function(err,model){
        Media.count({'model.entity': model._id}, function(err, media){
            if(media){
                console.log(media);
            }
        });

        model.total_media = 15;

        responders.sendJsonOrError(err, res, model, next);
    });
});
```

Problem is, that the code:

```
 model.total_media = 15;
```

Is not showing up in the responder, which is strange, because if I clean the object with: model = []; it returns empty.

Once I add lean() to my query, it returns the total_media in the responder, but then I get the problem that when I do like this:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
qbuilder.byId(Model,req)
    .exec(
    function(err,model){
        Media.count({'model.entity': model._id}, function(err, media){
            if(media){
                model.total_media = media;
            }
        });

        responders.sendJsonOrError(err, res, model, next);
    });
});
```

It is not populating the total_media, is there any other way to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. The response is sending before you assign  values.

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
qbuilder.byId(Model,req)
.lean().exec(
function(err,model){
    Media.count({'model.entity': model._id}, function(err, media){
        if(media){
            model.total_media = media;

        }
    responders.sendJsonOrError(err, res, model, next);
    });


});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this does not work, but when I add .lean() to the query it does, do you know what difference this actually makes?

Comment: You cannot add fileds to mongoDb object. lean() will convert mongoDb object to the normal json object.